# Como salvar arquivo JSON com Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, banco-de-dados, node.js

Quero fazer um site para testar algumas coisas. O site esta rodando em meu servidor em casa feito com o Wamp. Me disseram que eu poderia fazer um pequeno banco de dados usando arquivos JSON. Eu tenho um arquivo JSON na pasta do site que contem o seguinte:

```
[
        { 
            "titulo":"Filme A",
            "titulo original":"Movie A",
            "duracao":"120 min",
            "genero":"Genero 1",
            "Atores":"Nome 1, Nome 2",
            "Rate":"1",
            "Visto":"sim"
        },
        {
            "titulo":"Filme B",
            "titulo original":"Movie B",
            "duracao":"160 min",
            "genero":"Genero 2",
            "Atores":"Nome 1, Nome 2",
            "Rate":"2",
             "Visto":"sim"
        },
        {
            "titulo":"Filme C",
            "titulo original":"Movie C",
            "duracao":"140 min",
            "genero":"Genero 3",
            "Atores":"Nome 1, Nome 2",
            "Rate":"",
             "Visto":"nao"
        }
]
```

Com a ajuda de vocês eu consegui listar as propriedades desses objetos do array JSON.

Agora estou tentando salvar um novo objeto dentro desse array JSON através de informações que o usuário coloca quando são feitas as perguntas e pra isso eu preciso de um *scripting* no lado do servidor, eu escolhi o Node.js por estar um pouco mais familiarizado com o JavaScript. Tenho poucos conhecimentos e quase nenhum de Node.js. Mas mesmo assim gostaria de qualquer ajuda de vocês para eu tentar aprender alguma coisa. Tenho lido na internet sobre o node.js e JSON mas ainda não entendi como salvar o JSON no servidor usando o node. Qualquer explicação será de muita ajuda.

Veja no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pedrogelli/LAapR/4/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O mais indicado, que foi citado pelo Joel é sim de fato utilizar o Mongo, mas caso tenha interesse em utilizar uma API de manipulação de arquivos no Node.JS, você pode utilizar a [Filesystem API](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html), veja um exemplo abaixo

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test", "Hey there!", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    }
});
```

Ou então como o exemplo abaixo, pode ser a utilização do Node.JS com conexão com o [MongoDB](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/)

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
Grid = mongo.Grid;

// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, db) {
    if(err) return console.dir(err);

    var grid = new Grid(db, 'fs');
    var buffer = new Buffer("Hello world");
    grid.put(buffer, {metadata:{category:'text'}, content_type: 'text'}, function(err, fileInfo) {
        if(!err) {
             console.log("Finished writing file to Mongo");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Não entendi direito o que seria a API Filesystem. Digitar o código que você mostrou primeiro insere _"Hey there!"_ na data base, mas que data-base é essa? É algum arquivo JSON?

Comment: Na verdade ele só está escrevendo no arquivo a frase "Hey There!", em um arquivo físico e não em banco.

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo usares uma base de dados JSON MongoDB em Node.js.

http://nodebr.com/nodejs-e-mongodb-introducao-ao-mongoose/

Recomendo em aprender e ler mais em como usar MongoDB:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/getting-started-with-mongodb/

https://education.mongodb.com/

Comment: Estava mesmo lendo nesse site, mas estou com um problema pra instalar o Mongoose. Consegui instalar o MongoDB e iniciar ele tranquilo. Mas instalar o Mongoose não. Fiz como orientado no link que você me passou mas diz que não esta no registro do npm. Procurei no google por Mongoose e achei um que me pareceu ser mas quando eu o inicio da o seguinte erro:  _"Falied to set option [listening_port]: Cannot bind to port"_

Comment: hmmm devia dar! Esta listado no npm: https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose

Comment: Desculpe, digitei o comando em um prompt novo e funcionou. No link que você me passou, o autor conecta a DB referindo _mongodb://localhost/test_ "teste de DB do MongoDB". No meu caso o teste ficou em  _data\db_. Eu tenho que alterar o local de DB do Mongo pra minha pasta www no servidor wamp?

Comment: Esse código deve ser escrito ou chamado quando a pagina termina de carregar? @JoelCunhaFerreira

Comment: Você poderia dar detalhes sobre o assunto? Respostas apenas com links não sobrevivem ao tempo que é o nosso objetivo: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links